# Prove that if $\phi$ is invertible operator of V space, then $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ has the same invariant subspaces.

Tags: operator-theory, invariant-subspace

Prove that if $\phi$ is invertible operator of V space, then $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ has the same invariant subspaces. I know how to prove this statement for finite V. (Wish it is right) : Let $W$ be invariant subspace for $\phi$, then $\phi(W)\subset W$. If W is finite and $\phi$ is invertible $\Rightarrow$ $\phi\mid_W : W \rightarrow W$ is bijection, that's why for every $v\in W$ there exist $v'\in W$ such that $\phi(v) = v' \Rightarrow \phi^{-1}(\phi(v)) = \phi^{-1}(v')\Rightarrow v = \phi^{-1}(v') \Rightarrow \phi^{-1}(W)\subset W$.

But I don't know how to deal with infinite V. Can I do the same or it is completely different solution? Can you help me?

Comment: Are you assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: Actually, it can be finite or infinite, that is why I want to know how solve it for two cases. (If I did not answered you question, please, let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the assertion that you wish to prove is this:

> If $V$ is a vector space, $\phi\colon V\longrightarrow V$ is an invertible linear map and $W\subset V$ is a subspace such that $\phi(W)\subset W$, then $\phi^{-1}(W)\subset W$.

If that's so, then you cannot prove it, since it is false. Let $V$ be the real vector space of all functions from $\mathbb R$ into itself, let $\bigl(\phi(f)\bigr)(x)=f(x-1)$ and let $W=\{f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\,|\,x<0\implies f(x)=0\}$. Then $\phi(W)\subset W$. However, if you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\1&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}\end{array}$$then $f\in W$, but $\phi^{-1}(f)\notin W$, since $\bigl(\phi^{-1}(f)\bigr)\left(-\frac12\right)=1$.

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you so much for counterexample. am I right that $(\phi^{-1}(f))(-\frac{1}{2}) = 1$, because $(\phi^{-1}(f))(x) = f(x+1)$? And is it true statement for finite V and is my solution right then?

Comment: Your computation is correct. But I am quite confused with your term “finite”. Do you mean finite **set**? Or finite-**dimensional** space?

Comment: I meant finite-dimensional, because if I am not mistaken if V is finite dimensional we can say that $\phi|_W : W \rightarrow W$ is bijection

Comment: Then, yes, you are absolutely right.